# Meteor user always undefined in client side

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have one question, I am new in MeteorJS and think I need some help. I implemented email account verification. And next I would like log in user, but only if user is verified. And here is problem because always `Meteor.user()` is undefined in client. Could you help me and explain how I am doing wrong?

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){ 
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        verified: this.props.currentUser.emails[0].verified
    };
}

render(){

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect fluid>
                <nav className="sideBar-menu">
                    <div className="pull-right sidebar-right">
                        <ButtonToolbar className="pull-left sidebar-toolbar">
                            {!this.state.verified && <Button>Sign in</Button>}
                            {this.state.verified && <Button>Sign out</Button>}
                            <Button bsStyle="danger">Sign up</Button>
                        </ButtonToolbar>                    
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </Navbar>            
        </div>
    )
  }
}

const dataHOC = withTracker((props)=>{
   return {
      currentUser: Meteor.user()
   }
})(App);

export default dataHOC
```

Comment: Did my answer help you with this issue or is there still anything left that has not been solved regarding this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Meteor.user()` only returns an object of the current user, once the user has signed in. You can't therefore use properties on `currentUser` if no user is logged in.

Your state could therefore use two values for logged-in and verified:

```js
 const currentUser = this.props.currentUser
 this.state = {
   loggedIn: currentUser,
   verified: currentUser && currentUser.emails[0].verified
 };
```

And your render code will then display the `sign-in` element if there is no logged-in status:

```js
<ButtonToolbar className="pull-left sidebar-toolbar">
  {!this.state.loggedIn && <Button>Sign in</Button>}          
  { this.state.loggedIn && <Button>Sign out</Button>}
  <Button bsStyle="danger">Sign up</Button>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

You can then use `verified` to display further information such as a notification that you user has not yet been verified and show only content for verified users.

**Security note:** Note, that this is all just UI-candy and if you really want to prevent unverified users from subscribing to data or calling certain methods / update data you should always check for `user.emails[i].verified` in the methods and publications.